# Cannot get table to vertical-align in the middle

Tags: css

I have the following code, and my table(the table contains the two text lines next to the image) just does not want to align vertically in the middle of the div. What to do?
Please note that I used a table for my two text lines(laminin beauty and perfectly put together), since they have different styles and I want them justified, so I put align= center on their td tags... (justify text property only works when text is in the same tag...) . My website: http://lamininbeauty.co.za/index2.html

HTML:

```
        <div id="header">
            <img class="massage" src="images/massage.png" border="none" alt="face massage" />
            <div class="headerDiv">
                <table margin="0" padding="0">
                <tr><td align="center" class="headerText1">Laminin Beauty</td></tr>
                <tr><td align="center" class="headerText2">"Perfectly put together"</td></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #000000;
}

#header img{
    margin-left: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

#header div.headerDiv{
    display: table-cell;
    margin-left: 80px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.headerText1{
    color: #fff;
    font-family: impact;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.headerText2{
    color: #ee00ee;
    font-family: century gothic;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the div containing the table have a fixed height of 100px, since that's the height of your Wrapper div.  Then, make the height of the table 100%.  Here's a screenshot of what it did for me, not entirely sure if this is what you want: http://screencast.com/t/cbwcBbAoM3cZ

Comment: thank you, good direction you're heading, but I don't like the space between the cells containing the text. I always use display: table-cell and vertical-align: middle and that always centers my stuff vertically, but for some reason it does not work now

Comment: you could always vertical-align: bottom the top cell, and then vertical-align: top the second cell if that helps...using the same css i provided in my answer also.

Comment: great thinking, thanks, for my model, this is perfect. appreciate

Answer (score 0):

If the main header div will always be 100px high, remove the `display` property from the `headerDiv` element and add `margin-top: 12px;`.

Also it should have `display: inline-block` added and possibly the left margin decreased to compensate. The display property alteration will make it push off the image, not the left side of the document, as it should.

Also, if you want the two pieces of text to be aligned on the left, add `text-align: left` to the table tag.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I don't think you understand my question. Aligning any elements by making use of margins is very bad practice. Also, I wanted my text to be justified, not aligned left. It is aligned left if I do not put in in the table td tags with properties align="center"

Comment: I understand that using negative values in margins is considered bad practice, but what's wrong with a little on top of an element? :|